# How to solve: EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir 'C:\Users\OKR\Desktop\MeetUp' after generating apk failed in React Native?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, apk

I'm trying to test my React Native apk app file.

Here are the steps I made before generate the apk:

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

then

```
cd android && .\gradlew assembleRelease -x bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
```

I created the key store about a month ago. At that time, I built a AAB to publish to Play Store

I didn't re-generate a new one before doing this

And here's the behavior:
[It can't open](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dxCKpns8FNWggU3uxh_rdEKG8Vxhfq-G)

I uploaded the apk to a social media app called: Zalo. Then downloaded it to my phone. At first I can't open since the Play Store blocked it. Only when I disabled that ability of Play Service in Settings than I could download it

**EDIT 1**:
I follow instructions on how to generate the apk from Android Studio, but at the end, it crashes and gives the error:

```
the transform cache was reset.
EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir 'C:\Users\OKR\Desktop\MeetUp'
```

I don't know why this happens since I don't have that folder in the `Desktop`

**PLEASE HELP MEEEE**

Comment: Try to make it in the Android Studio.

Comment: Follow its steps: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QQEiduce95c&t=51s

Comment: Thanks for the link and comment @Iffat . However after I generated APK with my existing key store, I got the error ```EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir 'C:\Users\OKR\Desktop\MeetUp'```. It's so weird beause I don't have that folder in the ```Desktop```. (My main folder is MeetUp2 in MeetupApp/Development/Meetup2). Please help me

Comment: try to put this `C:\Users\OKR\Desktop\MeetUp` path in your C drives `path bar`, and see if it is taking you there or not. And the other way is you can create a fresh key for your apk file. I always create a new key for my apk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank @Iffat for your support. After all I realized that I'm using a key store for debug store. That is indeed the reason why I can't generate my APK

I had to create a new key store for release mode and work on my terminal instead Android Studio . It works.

If anyone encounter the issue, you can read this post here, which was very helpful to me

[How to generate a release apk_The right way](https://medium.com/@shreyasnisal/solved-packing-error-in-react-native-release-apk-f887687edc4f)

Answer (score 1):

It could mean you already have an app release generated in the destination folder for the new one.
I had the same issue, simply changed my destination folder when exporting through Android Studio and it was solved.